# Is it possible to share an audio file and play within Facebook

Tags: facebook, audio, facebook-graph

I have a msuic page section and have FB share button. Is it possible to share audio file and play within facebook?

I have tried to add FB graphs but no luck

```
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo "audio";  ?>" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="<?php $musiclink = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'music_record_link', true );if ( ! empty( $musiclink ) ) {echo $musiclink;}?>" />
<meta property="og:audio:secure_url" content="<?php $musiclink = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'music_record_link', true );if ( ! empty( $musiclink ) ) {echo $musiclink;}?>"/>
<meta property="og:audio:height" content="250" />
<meta property="og:audio:width" content="487" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" /> 
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/mp3" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not doable via facebook. You can send sound files via message, and they can be played in the messages. Facebook doesn't have an option to put up only audio files.

You have to turn your MP3 file into a video file then add a picture so it can play or use some external service for this.

For example, if you upload your file to https://clyp.it/ you can share your audio on facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Josip Ivic. What you mean by saying that I nee to turn my MP3 file into video file please?

Comment: Well, upload it to youtube for example, and put album art or just play over it and share it. That's the most easiest way to do this.

Comment: The issue is that i need to share it from my website not from youtube for eample

Comment: Use https://clyp.it/ then? Can you put more details? How do you mean from your website? Which format is up? Do you have play option on site?

Comment: Yes i have play option. Am using jwplayer for embedding the audio files. Share button is under the music item which should share that current music item

Comment: When you share it on facebook, what happens? It shares only link?

Comment: Yes it shares just a link to music single page, image, description

Comment: Well, then there's no option for it to be shared on facebook and automatically play like video files. You need to use external service for this.

Comment: Hmm i see. What other external sevices options there were?

Comment: Well, I always use youtube for sharing like that. But, as i said, clyp.it is ok. Try it.